# The sub-specifier in printf

Tags: c, printf, mingw32

```
int main ()
{
    float Num = 3254.4;
    printf("%06.4f",Num);
    return 0;
}
```

Why it doesn't print `003254.3999` as my expectation, but `3254.3999`?

[I've completely read this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your Reference:

width:

Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

Note that this counts all characters including the . and the four decimal places

6 to the left + 4 to the right + 1 for decimal = **11** *(not 10)*

What you want is "%011.4f"

Tested this:

```
printf("%011.4f\n", 1.4);
```

result is:

```
000001.4000  // note 6 to the left and 4 to the right (plus the .) = 11
```

Comment: OP thinks the `'6'` applies only to what's on the left of the `'.'`. He doesn't necessarily want it padded with two `'0'`s.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey From his question he wants "003254.3999" isn't that padded with 00?

Comment: He doesn't specify that's what he wants.  That's just semantics though.  Well done.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `6` to `10` or greater and you will see the `0` padding.  The `6` you are specifying is the minimum characters it'll print.  Your number (3254.3999) has nine.

Comment: yes tested this: `printf("%011.4f\n", 1.2344);` result is `000001.2344`  <6>.<4>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main ()
{
    float Num = 3254.4;
    printf("%011.4f",Num);
    return 0;
}
```

ie, try to change the specifier value greater than 6 since you are specifying the minimum characters limit.

Comment: Need the `0` in front of `10`: `printf("%010.4f",Num);`

Comment: 6+4+1 = 11 not 10 -- 6 to the left + 4 to the right + 1 for decimal

Answer (score 1):

This is because `6` is used to right justify the output to 6 places. Since the output comes to be width of 9 places its effect is not visible.If you increase the width then you can see the effect.

Comment: The output width is 9 actually.